# Git Flowでgit flow init をした時に「error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません」

Tags: git

現在、AWSのEC2上で開発をしています。
git flow をインストールし、git flow initを行うと

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx sample]$ git flow init

```
Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
- master
Branch name for production releases: [master] master
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/html/dev1/tomato/.git/index.lock': 許可があ        りません

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? [feature/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
Release branches? [release/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
Hotfix branches? [hotfix/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
Support branches? [support/] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
Version tag prefix? [] 
error: could not lock config file .git/config: 許可がありません
```

と表示されます。

また、権限関係の問題かと思い、configの権限を
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user    264  9月 30 17:23 config

のように変更しているのですが、それでもうまくいきません。
どなたか分かる方いらっしゃらないでしょうか。

Comment: リポジトリ内のファイルやディレクトリのオーナーは全て `ec2-user` なのでしょうか？ もしかして別のユーザーが過去に作成したリポジトリなのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ディレクトリのオーナーや権限の問題かと思います。

```
ls -ld ..
```

で確認して見てください。
（/var/www/ は慣習的に公開用のディレクトリです。ご存知とは思いますがお気を付けください）

Answer (score 0):

> fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/html/dev1/tomato/.git/index.lock'

`/var/www/html/dev1/tomato/.git` ディレクトリに書込権限がないためロックファイルを作成出来ずエラーになってると思います。

`chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html/dev1/tomato` で オーナーを `ec2-user` に変更してください。